# Isn't spring webflux default respose (sse) useless due to the xhttp request limitation?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I'm studying webflux and reactive in general, but I found what, according to me, is a serious flaw: you make reactive application for web, at least in 90% of cases.

But, as you probably know, web browsers only allow a limited number of active connections to the server (sse, server sent events).

So, this means that if I make a web application I'd have to make sure that at most 2-3 reactive streams are in the same page or everything would block.

So I was wondering: why in webflux they don't leverage on websockets that don't have this limitation? I'm trying to do it with custom means but I was expecting an out-of-the-box.

Given that webflux was born in 2013 and the SSE limitation is known by 199x why didn't the creators not think about it? It seems like a new paradigm born old to me...

Comment: You can use rsocket if you want websockets. Webflux is for HTTP only AFAIK

Comment: Also the reason SSE is typically preferred is because it is easier/faster to implement.